# any better way of Sorting my dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

After I retrieve the country names in English, I convert the country names to localized versions, I need to sort those names again, so I used `SortDropDownList`. Here, after I sort my `DropDownList` Items, I am losing the `PrivacyOption` attribute I set.

Can someone suggest solutions to sort my `DropDownList` while also retaining the `PrivacyOption` attribute?

I am using asp.net4.0 along with C# as `CodeBehind`:

```
int iCount = 1;

//fetch country names in English
List<CountryInfo> countryInfo = ReturnAllCountriesInfo();

foreach (CountryInfo c in countryInfo)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(
        LocalizationUtility.GetResourceString(c.ResourceKeyName))))
    {
        ListItem l = new ListItem();
        l.Text = Convert.ToString(
                    LocalizationUtility.GetResourceString(c.ResourceKeyName));
        l.Value = Convert.ToString(
                    LocalizationUtility.GetResourceString(c.ResourceKeyName));
        //True /False*
        l.Attributes.Add("PrivacyOption", *Convert.ToString(c.PrivacyOption));

        drpCountryRegion.Items.Insert(iCount, l);
        iCount++;
    }
    //sorts the dropdownlist loaded with country names localized language
    SortDropDownList(ref this.drpCountryRegion);  
}
```

And the code to `SortDropDownList` items:

```
private void SortDropDownList(ref DropDownList objDDL)
{
    ArrayList textList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList valueList = new ArrayList();

    foreach (ListItem li in objDDL.Items)
    {
        textList.Add(li.Text);

    }

    textList.Sort();

    foreach (object item in textList)
    {
        string value = objDDL.Items.FindByText(item.ToString()).Value;
        valueList.Add(value);
    }
    objDDL.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < textList.Count; i++)
    {
        ListItem objItem = new ListItem(textList[i].ToString(), 
               valueList[i].ToString());              

        objDDL.Items.Add(objItem);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the data before you populate the DropDownList.

```
IEnumerable<Country> sortedCountries = countries.OrderBy(
                c => LocalizationUtility.GetResourceString(c.ResourceKeyName));

foreach (Country country in sortedCountries)
{
    string name = LocalizationUtility.GetResourceString(country.ResourceKeyName);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        ListItem item = new ListItem(name);
        item.Attributes.Add(
             "PrivacyOption", 
             Convert.ToString(country.PrivacyOption));
        drpCountryRegion.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about sorting the information in a `SortedDictionary` instead of a `List`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure if I understand how your implementation of `SortDropDownList` method works. However, I can suggest using a `List<KeyValue<string, string>>` to bind to your `DropDownList`. You can use the English part and local part in your `KeyValuePair` and sort accordingly.